# Negation with indefinite article

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation

Usually when negating a sentence, if the direct object comes with an indefinite article (*un*/*une*/*des*), the article should be changed to *de*:

> J'ai mangé **une** pomme ce matin.
>
> Je n'ai pas mangé **de** pomme ce matin.

This rule does not apply if the verb is *être*:

> C'est **un** canard.
>
> Ce n'est pas **un** canard.

**Are there any other cases when this rule does not apply (that is, when we still use an indefinite article in a negative sentence)?** For example, if we want to negate

> Cet étudiant mérite **une** bonne note.

should we say

> Cet étudiant ne mérite pas **une** bonne note.

or

> Cet étudiant ne mérite pas **de** bonne note.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the rule you cite, both forms are heard, especially with *ne mérite pas*:

> *Cet étudiant ne mérite pas de bonne note.*
>
> *Cet étudiant ne mérite pas une bonne note.*

*Une* in the second sentence might be taken as a numeral, not an indefinite article so using it wouldn't break the rule. A full sentence without anything implicit could also be:

> *Cet étudiant ne mérite pas une bonne note, il mérite une mauvaise note !*

Another advantage of using *une*, especially in a spoken situation, is that there is no ambiguity about the number of notes deserved while the first form can be misunderstood as *Cet étudiant ne mérite pas de bonnes notes*.

---

*Jean de La Fontaine* in a [letter to *Madame de Montespan*](http://lettres.ac-rouen.fr/francais/fables/Livre7.html):

> *Je ne mérite pas une faveur si grande ;*

It can be argued *une* is used here to make an alexandrine though.

Answer (score 0):

There is another exception added to the verb "être", this is the opposition.

```
Cet étudiant mérite une bonne note.
```

we should say

```
Cet étudiant ne mérite pas de bonne note.
```

or with opposition, for example :

```
Cet étudiant ne mérite pas une bonne note, mais une excellente note !
```

Partitive articles (du, de la, de l') follow same rules.

Comment: Je n'ai pas mangé une pomme ce matin, mais deux !

Comment: This is a correct example of opposition use ;)